# Is there a way to make a very simple IE browser with java?

Tags: java, linux, vb.net

I have a small project that i was wondering if it is possible to do with java. 
I know that VB .net has the ability to make a simple web browser using an Internet explorer interface. I was wanting to do the same thing with java. Unless somebody knows how to compile VB on linux and would like to explain it to me.

Please tell me if you need anymore information.

Comment: Huh... IE on Linux? That sounds interesting; hopefully it's IE 9 and not IE 6?

Comment: actually i am running on linux but this for a windows machine 
Edit: also the reason i am asking is because there is an online program that only works in IE and I don't want the people using to be able to browse the internet using IE. I just want a simple screen with the underlying code. This is for a mechanic shop using a program called Mitchell

Answer (score 0):

JEditorPane has limited HTML rendering support, but no javascript engine

Answer (score 0):

If you want Internet Explorer specifically, it's not going to be possible in the same way. VB.net uses the part of Internet Explorer that is built into the system. In other words, it is referencing a part of the Windows system, so you need to be running Windows to use it, regardless of the language.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to run IE on linux, though, check out http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a tool such as http://www.ezjcom.com/ to get a COM wrapper in Java, from there you can embed IE as an ActiveX object.

All of these pieces might make it a little slow or cumbersome, but it should be possible.

Comment: would this work to just get a browser window object without any of the toolbars?

Comment: That I do not know: I am familiar with the pieces of the puzzle, but have not put them together myself. I believe there are ways to embed IE without the UI wrapper (menu, borders, titles, status bar, etc), however, I am not sure how. I just know I have seen it.